# Enum in interfaces

Tags: interfaces

Following the documentation I try to add a enum to my interface. Inside the interface I have a method called get that returns one of the enum value. Im trying to add the enum to the interface, because in the get function one of the return value is one value of the enum. I follow this example.

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.1/contracts.html#interfaces

Error:

> TypeError: Enumerable cannot be declared in interfaces

Is wrong the docu??

Comment: The compiler solidity version is the 0.4.24

Comment: Not possible unfortunately (at least up to v0.4.25, maybe different in v0.5 onward).

Comment: Thx @goodvibration. So there is no way to set a enum like a return paramter in 0.4.24 no?

Comment: Not in an interface (or more generally, you can use an `enum` only within the scope of the contract where it is declared).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the docs for the version of the compiler you're using, located [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html), it says under note 5 under the Interfaces header that they cannot define enums. If you want the ability to do that, you'll have to upgrade to 0.5.0+

Comment: Thx for the answer